# How to get products by categories in magento 2

Tags: api, soap, categories, magento2, product

Does anyone know how I can get a list of products belonging to a specific category with SOAP V2 in Magento 2 ?

Answer (score 1):

Like the following.

```
GET /categories/:id/products
```

Problem is you wont get full product details, even name